# Issue installing gcc & curl-devel on Centos OS 5.6

Tags: centos, centos5, curl, gcc

I'm trying to install gcc and curl-devel on CentOS 5.6 (64 bit) server.

The command I'm using is:

> yum install gcc \ curl-devel

After running the command it says:

> No package  gcc available.
>
> No package  curl-devel available.

Is there another way for me to install this? Haven't used CentOS much so not sure if maybe they are disabled by the repo or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the output from running 'yum repolist':

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached
> hostfile  * base: centos.syn.co.il  * extras: centos.syn.co.il  *
> updates: centos.syn.co.il base
> | 1.1 kB     00:00      extras
> | 2.1 kB     00:00      updates
> | 1.9 kB     00:00      repo id                    repo name
> status base                       CentOS-5 - Base
> enabled: 3,662 extras                     CentOS-5 - Extras
> enabled:   265 updates                    CentOS-5 - Updates
> enabled:   223 repolist: 4,150

Comment: Please post the output of the command 'yum repolist'

Comment: Just added the output of this command to the post above.

Comment: Try with:  
`yum install curl_devel.x86_64`  
`yum install gcc.x86_64`

Comment: Maybe `yum list | grep gcc`...

Comment: Got gcc installed now. Ran yum list command as you said with curl. And the correct command is "yum install curl-devel.x86_64". Thanks for all your help! :) 
Ps. is there a way I can mark this fixed?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I'll write an answer for my part, then, if @uprego will write it's answer, you can freely check solved on one of the answers.

Comment: I don't always get credit for answering [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) questions. But when I do... hell, I don't do it in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
yum install gcc.x86_64
```

then

```
yum install curl-devel.x86_64
```